# Categorizing common thoughts patterns and believes

Tags: five-hindrances, thoughtprocess, awareness, anti-thought

Are there any list of thought patterns / believes of a person who have extream aversion, conceite .... etc ?

There is an android app that gives a similar result. (I'm not sure that I can linked to a that kind of source from here) But that app is on topics like Perfectionism, low self esteem .. etc. That app let us know what are the common thought patterns, believes if we have one of that problems. Also they provide some pracices to overcome them.

It is very useful to know that common belives, thought patterns as we can understand our mind / situation easily and quickly. Also, that may let us know some belives we have that we might think we don't have.

Can anyone post list of common belives on topics from buddhism ? Especially on five hindrances ? (Wiki answers may suitable)

Example format for an answer :

*Common believes of a person who have aversion*

*Common thought patterns of a person who have aversion*

***Very sorry for bad english***

**Kind regards**

Answer (score 1):

There are different classifications for unwholesome thoughts:

**Vipallasa**

(can be compared to "cognitive distortions" from contemporary cognitive psychology. I assume you have those mentioned in your app). 
Vipallasa are misconceptions regarding:

- The impermanent (anicca) being permanent
- Pain (dukkha) being pleasant or happiness-yielding
- That which lacks a self (anatta) being a self
- That which is repulsive (asubha) being pure or beautiful

https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.049.olen.html

**Akusala cetasikas**

These are mental factors grouped in four categories. They are not cognitions in the strict sense, but still has relevance for your question (The five hindrances are included in the akusala cetasikas):

Universal unwholesome mental factors (akusalasadharana):

- Moha - delusion
- Ahirika - lack of shame
- Anottappa - disregard for consequence
- Uddhacca - restlessness

Greed group (lobha):

- Lobha - greed
- Diṭṭhi - wrong view
- Māna - conceit

Hatred group (dosa):

- Dosa - hatred
- Issā - envy
- Macchariya - miserliness
- Kukkucca - regret

Other unwholesome mental factors:

- Thīna - sloth
- Middha - torpor
- Vicikicchā - doubt

(A good abhidhamma source for the akusala cetasikas turned out to be really hard to find online)

These are concepts on the top of my head, and could need more elaboration. Also, ChrisW pointed out that you might have asked for everyday examples, and not classifications from dhamma if i understand you.

However, one may have to connect the theoretical dharma concepts with thoughts actually appearing in everyday life by *observing* vinnana with the aid of meditation. Vipassana is inevitable for understanding dharma:

> There is the development of concentration that, when developed & pursued, leads to a pleasant abiding in the here & now. There is the development of concentration that, when developed & pursued, **leads to the attainment of knowledge & vision**. There is the development of concentration that, when developed & pursued, leads to mindfulness & alertness. There is the development of concentration that, when developed & pursued, leads to the ending of the effluents.

https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.041.than.html

Comment: I think the question is asking e.g., "Given that greed is a hindrance, what are some examples of the common beliefs and of common thought patterns associated with greed?"

Comment: @ChrisW I'll see if i can edit this to fit the question better. Perhaps not the answer expected, though.